# error or apache jasper jasperexception

Tags: jsp

I am using eclipse and jslt

I have added jslt jar file and import jslt "C" and "fmt". But I am still getting an error for fmt. Line 40 is this:

```
value="${peopleList[1].salary}"
```

**below is the Error I am getting:**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /ex01_3.jsp (line: 40, column: 10) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:275)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:107)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1241)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:879)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1536)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:898)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1536)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:464)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1853)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Here is Code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:useBean id="people" scope="session" class="MyPackage.Bean02">
</jsp:useBean>

          <fmt:formatNumber type="currency"
         value="${peopleList[i].salary}"
         minFractionDigits="2"
         maxFractionDigits="2"/>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your taglib import is wrong for `fmt`. It's older version. Change it to

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
```